# Nativescript continuous delivery

Tags: nativescript, continuous-delivery

I've just started learning and using nativescript; everything seems alright and I'm making progress, but I haven't been able to find a solution for continuous delivery. (on push on master branch in bitbucket, I want to automatically make the build and distribute it).
I've tried appcenter from Microsoft (I used it before for Xamarin) but could not make it work.

Comment: currently there isn't any option available for providing soft updates to nativescript app. it's in their 2019 milestone.

Comment: I really appreciate the comment. Do you know of any other solutions for delivering builds beside using Sidekick?

Comment: there also needed it but still didn't find any solid workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched for multiple solutions. I've retried with VS appcenter, there was an example or two on google(e.g. https://github.com/skhye05/nativescript-app-center ), but did not work for me.
I guess I'll close the ticket for now.

Answer (score 1):

I use bitrise (https://www.bitrise.io/). It integrates with bitbucket for CI and also offers scheduled builds. There are free plans available. Takes a little config to get working with NativeScript, but worth it so far.